# Laravel lost session after a few requests/page refresh

Tags: laravel, session

Unfortunately I have a problem with the laravel-session:

When I add a few products to the sessioned shopping-cart and reload the page a few times, the session-data will be lost completely.

The session config:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => null,
'secure' => false,
'http_only' => true,
```

(all the default)

Laravel Version:
5.2.43

The issue appears locally (xampp) and on the server (forge). So I suspect that there is not a server problem.

I've tried different solutions with the middleware, but unfortunately without any success. It looks like, the session were deleted after some requests/page reloads randomly. (sometimes after 5, sometimes by 20)

I found out when I load images per request (not directly via file), the session will be lost more often.

Session-percistence is apparently a big problem for laravel-beginners.
So many boards and forums are full of solutions, but nothing i found solves my problem.

Is there any experience?

Thanks!

Comment: What driver is specified in your .env file? Perhaps you could switch to another driver.

Comment: @Jan in .env also: SESSION_DRIVER=file. Switch to a different driver, it's only a workaround, not a solution I think.

Comment: Can you try and change it to 'cookie' or 'database'?

Comment: cookie driver causes same issue. Next i test the database driver...

Comment: first the database driver works fine, but when I reload the page for about 100-150 times the session will be lost :(

Comment: Is it possible this issue caused by "Session Sweeping Lottery" in the config/session.php ? Or i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it seems "Session Sweeping Lottery" is not the trigger for my problem.
Does anybody here has an idea? I'm helpless at the moment.

Comment: Were you ever able to come up with solution? I'm having same issue with random requests failing to recover session. Just tried modifying lottery-value from 100 to 500 and trying to see if it makes a difference. Previously this issue was resolved by "php artisan config:cache", but after upgrading to Laravel 8 issue has started to happen more often. I'm also using XAMPP as my dev-server, but I'm not having this issue on *nix with Apache.